# Infinite Loop when using useEffect, array formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-effect

I am getting an infinite loop when using useEffect trying to manipulate data. I have an array (ie. todos) of objects and every time the array is changed, I wanted to go through and do some modifications to the array.

I only want the useEffect to run when the list of todos passed into the function has changed so that I can update each one.

```
function useFormatTodoData(todos = [], userSelectedTime) {
  const [editedTodos, setEditedTodos] = useState(todos);

  const editTodos = useCallback(() => {
    return todos.map(todo => {
    return {
      time: userSelectedTime, 
      ...todo
    }
    })
  }, [todos]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setEditedTodos(editTodos());
    
  }, [todos, editLineups]);
  return editedTodos;
}

export default useFormatTodoData;
```

Comment: `todos` is being updated in the `useEffect` which triggers the `useEffect` to update `todos`, ad infinitum.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it

Comment: Why does `editTodos` need to be in a useEffect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - `editTodos` needs to be inside the useEffect so that it is run every time an update to the `todos` array occurs. 

`todos` is not being updated inside the useEffect, the map is returning a new array

Comment: @ScottDivelbiss I was mistaken. `todos` is not updated, but `editedTodos` is. `userSelectedTime` is missing from the useCallback, and `editTodos` is missing from the useEffect. `editLineups` is unnecessary.